# Extending layout by other layer in Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm generating an atlas using one point layer as a coverage vector and other layers that show up depending on the coverage vector value. Everything works fine, however, I want to see one vector layer as a whole, not clipped by default Atlas size. What should I do?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a second map showing an [oveview](https://imgur.com/a/sGb9nQS)?

Comment: @BERA yes! this is what I need

Comment: @BERA on the second thought, I guess it's not quite what I exactly need. The [example](https://imgur.com/a/7d8LJLc) shows that the blue vector layer is cropped - I want to see the whole layer, only zoomed to this exact layer, but not the whole country/city

Answer (score 1):

You have a point layer (used as atlas) and a surface or line layer (depending on current atlas) and you have trouble to set the extent of your atlas to match your current surface or line layer extent

Different solutions :

- Use your surface or line layer as atlas. It will not work if you have for each atlas feature different feature.
- Use tool collect geometries on your line or surface layer based on unique id of atlas feature. Use the result as atlas layer and click on hide atlas layer.
- Keep your point layer as atlas layer but add a attribute to set the scale of your atlas, then use the scale on your layout.